# Import local modules in Python with relative path

Tags: python-3.x, python-module

```
TopLevelDir
├── CommonUtils
│   ├── setup.py
│   └── Sql
│       ├── class1.py
│       └── class2.py
├── Project1
│   ├── requirements.txt
│   ├── venv
│   ├── main.py
│   └── FolderA
│       ├── A_usesSqlClass1.py
│       └── A_usesSqlClass2.py
└── Project2
    ├── requirements.txt
    ├── venv
    ├── main.py
    └── FolderB
        ├── B_usesSqlClass1.py
        └── B_usesSqlClass2.py
```

I have the above folder structure for my projects.  I want the `CommonUtils` folder/module/package to be visible in all `.py` files in all projects.  Is there a way to do this **without** using absolute paths or altering `PYTHONPATH` (which I'm reluctant to do because I'm going to convert it to an `.exe` with PyInstaller and share it)?  I'm not ready to publish it to PyPI yet, either.

All variations of `import CommonUtils` or `from CommonUtils import *` in files A* and B* (e.g. `..\CommonUtils` etc.) fail with a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'CommonUtils'` error.